# Symfony sfFormFilters - when would you use it?

Tags: forms, symfony1, filter

So I'm somewhat aware of what sfFormFilter can do, but I'm more interested in when you would use it, or why. For the most part I don't understand why I'd use form filters when I can just use the forms.

Is there a conceptual difference? Or is there a feature/functional difference in the two?

If this is mentioned in the jobeet tutorial then I've definitely missed it and someone just pointing me in that direction would be cool

Answer (score 1):

`sfFormFilter` is the form that you see when you do `php symfony doctrine:generate-admin ...` and go to the `list` action of your new module, on the right side (depending on your admin theme).

This is the form used to filter your list. So you can edit this class if you're not happy with the generated form fields, need different widgets or change other configurations.

The example below is the form filter taken from `sf_guard_permission/list`:

[image]

Comment: Soo filters is pregenerated with generate-admin and used by admin users. Forms are what I'd expose to the end-users.

Comment: No. Filters are only for the filters form. If you edit one of the items on the list, you'll be using the Form. That form can be used by the admin or the end-user, you decide how to implement it.